# Add CAShapeLayer Animation to UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uibutton, cashapelayer

I was animating `CAShapeLayer`. It works fine but how add that `CAShapeLayer` animation for `UIButton`. Use `CAShapeLayer` animation for the `UIButton`

Comment: Have you tried setting it to the button's layer?